# Como criar colunas inexistentes em um DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ado.net, datatable

Aqui está minha consulta:

```
select 
u.nome as analista, 
s.descricao as situacao, 
count(*) as qtd                            
from tb_projeto p
inner join tb_usuario u on u.id_usuario = p.id_usuario
inner join tb_situacao s on s.id_situacao = p.id_situacao
group by analista, situacao
order by analista
```

E o resultado da mesma:

[image: postgre]

Quando eu recebo isto num DataTable eu faço alguns reboliços e transformo estas 3 colunas numa Cross Table, porém como nem todos os analistas tem os valores das quantidades "Reprovados" maior que zero ele não aparece no DataTable o que quebra o meu total na interface:

[image: ui]

```
public DataTable CrossTable(DataTable dtS, String leftColumn, String topField, String dataValue, String pFix = "F_")
    {
        if (dtS == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        DataTable dtOut = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtRowTitle = new DataTable();
        DataTable dtColHeader = new DataTable();

        dtRowTitle = dtS.DefaultView.ToTable(true, dtS.Columns[leftColumn].ColumnName);
        dtColHeader = dtS.DefaultView.ToTable(true, dtS.Columns[topField].ColumnName);

        DataColumn dColx = new DataColumn();            

        dColx.ColumnName = leftColumn;
        dColx.Caption = leftColumn;
        dtOut.Columns.Add(dColx);            

        foreach (DataRow drow in dtColHeader.Rows)
        {
            DataColumn dCol = new DataColumn();
            dCol.ColumnName = pFix + drow[topField].ToString().Trim();
            dtOut.Columns.Add(dCol);
        }

        DataColumn dColx2 = new DataColumn();
        dColx2.ColumnName = "TOTAL";
        dtOut.Columns.Add(dColx2);

        DataRow drowx;

        foreach (DataRow drow in dtRowTitle.Rows)
        {
            drowx = dtOut.NewRow();
            drowx[0] = drow[leftColumn];
            dtOut.Rows.Add(drowx);
        }

        Int32 xVal = 0, yVal = 0;
        string analista = null;
        int total = 0;

        foreach (DataRow mRow in dtS.Rows)
        {
            string xRowVal = mRow[leftColumn].ToString(), dataVal = mRow[dataValue].ToString(), yColVal = mRow[topField].ToString().Trim();

            foreach (DataRow nRow in dtOut.Rows)
            {
                if (xRowVal == nRow[0].ToString())
                {
                    for (xVal = 0; xVal < nRow.Table.Columns.Count; xVal++)
                    {
                        if (nRow.Table.Columns[xVal].ColumnName == pFix + yColVal)
                        {                                
                            if (xVal == 1)
                            {
                                total = 0;
                                analista = xRowVal;
                            }

                            Int32 rIndex = dtOut.Rows.IndexOf(nRow);
                            dtOut.Rows[rIndex][xVal] = dataVal;

                            if (analista == xRowVal)
                            {                                    
                                total += Convert.ToInt32(dataVal);
                            }

                            if (xVal + 2 == nRow.Table.Columns.Count)
                            {
                                dtOut.Rows[rIndex][3] = total.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        dtOut.DefaultView.Sort = dtOut.Columns[0].ColumnName;
        return dtOut;
    }
```

Com as colunas de "Reprovado" de alguns analistas nem sendo processadas o meu total fica errado. Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Ao fazer os **reboliços** verifique se o campo é `null` e atribua 0. Post o código do **reboliços** para facilitar a ajuda.

Comment: pronto cara, o reboliço foi adicionado.

Answer (score 1):

Se suas colunas do *select* e os registros da tabela tb_situacao forem sempre fixos, você pode fazer direto no seu *select*, desse jeito:

```
-- considerando que o id_situacao
-- 1 = 'APROVADO'
-- 2 = 'REPROVADO'

select
  u.nome ANALISTA,
  sum(case when (s.id_situacao = 1) then 1 else 0 end) APROVADO,
  sum(case when (s.id_situacao = 2) then 1 else 0 end) REPROVADO,
  count(*) TOTAL
from 
  tb_projeto as p
  inner join tb_usuario u on (u.id_usuario = p.id_usuario)
  inner join tb_situacao s on (s.id_situacao = p.id_situacao)
group by 
  ANALISTA
order by 
  ANALISTA
```

[Veja funcionando no SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6738f/10)

Caso você realmente queira fazer via código e usando seu *select*, você poderia fazer algo semelhante a isso:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

namespace Teste01
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dtEntrada = new DataTable ();
            dtEntrada.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("ANALISTA", typeof(String)));
            dtEntrada.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("SITUACAO", typeof(String)));
            dtEntrada.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("QTD", typeof(Int32)));

            dtEntrada.Rows.Add (new Object[] { "EDSON", "APROVADO", 1 });
            dtEntrada.Rows.Add (new Object[] { "EDSON", "REPROVADO", 2 });
            dtEntrada.Rows.Add (new Object[] { "EDUARDO RAMOS", "APROVADO", 3 });
            dtEntrada.Rows.Add (new Object[] { "EDUARDO TORQUATO", "APROVADO", 1 });
            dtEntrada.Rows.Add (new Object[] { "LUCAS", "APROVADO", 1 });
            dtEntrada.Rows.Add (new Object[] { "LUCAS", "REPROVADO", 1 });

            DataTable dtSaida = new DataTable ();
            dtSaida.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("ANALISTA", typeof(String)));
            dtSaida.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("APROVADO", typeof(Int32)));
            dtSaida.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("REPROVADO", typeof(Int32)));
            dtSaida.Columns.Add (new DataColumn ("TOTAL", typeof(Int32)));

            var lstAnalistas = (from a in dtEntrada.Select()
                                group a by a["ANALISTA"] into g
                                orderby g.Key
                                select (String) g.Key).ToList<String>();

            int aprovado, reprovado, total;

            foreach (var analista in lstAnalistas) {
                DataRow linhaAprovado = (from a in dtEntrada.Select ()
                                         where (String) a ["ANALISTA"] == analista && 
                                               (String) a ["SITUACAO"] == "APROVADO"
                                         select a).FirstOrDefault ();

                DataRow linhaReprovado = (from a in dtEntrada.Select ()
                                          where (String) a ["ANALISTA"] == analista && 
                                                (String) a ["SITUACAO"] == "REPROVADO"
                                          select a).FirstOrDefault ();

                if (linhaAprovado != null)
                    aprovado = (int) linhaAprovado ["QTD"];
                else
                    aprovado = 0;

                if (linhaReprovado != null)
                    reprovado = (int) linhaReprovado ["QTD"];
                else
                    reprovado = 0;

                total = aprovado + reprovado;
                dtSaida.Rows.Add (new Object[] { analista, aprovado, reprovado, total });
            }

            foreach (DataRow linha in dtSaida.Rows) {
                foreach (DataColumn coluna in dtSaida.Columns) {
                    Console.Write (linha [coluna.ColumnName].ToString () + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine ();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HyHAUZ)

Fique atento para a questão de nomes de analistas iguais, pode ser que seja necessário utilizar o id deles para diferenciá-los.

> **Nota:** a parte do código onde eu criei o dtEntrada foi somente para poder gerar uma saída com os dados que você informou.

**Extra**

[Conditional Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html)

Answer (score 0):

`coalesce` retorna o valor do segundo parâmetro se o primeiro for nulo

```
coalesce(count(*), 0) as qtd
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Clodoaldo, mas não foi! Vou postar o código em C# pra ver se ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Mateus, sugiro usar o pivot table na sua consulta. Essa função faz exatamente o que você quer, transforma linhas em colunas, e não é necessário fazer reboliços no seu código c#.